# HTML5 video not playing in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, video, html5-video

I've converted the file to three different formats: mp4, web, and ogv. According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=video) firefox supposedly supports both ogg and webm, but nothing is playing.

I converted the files using [Miro Converter](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/), according to other people this should work just fine. I believe Chrome picks up the webm file (if i rightclick -> open in new tab, it shows me the webm file), which is great.

URL to the site: http://dev.fristil.se/hbh/

I have a static image as a background. The video is suppose to display above it, so if it's not moving you can tell it's not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your server is not sending the correct mime type for the file.

It send `Content-Type: text/plain`

The HTML5 video may play  in Safari, Chrome and IE 9 but not Firefox or IE 7-8. If you fix the MIME-type issue, it will play in Firefox.

If you’re using the Apache web server or some derivative of Apache, you can use an AddType directive in your site-wide **httpd.conf** or in an **.htaccess** file in the directory where you store your video files. (If you use some other web server, consult your server’s documentation on how to set the Content-Type HTTP header for specific file types.)

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm

AddType audio/mpeg .mp3
AddType audio/ogg .ogg
AddType audio/mp4 .m4a
AddType audio/wav /wav
```

You have same question here: [Video file .ogv plays locally in Firefox, but not from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139969/video-file-ogv-plays-locally-in-firefox-but-not-from-server)
and more detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6145629/1081079

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it for firefox! I am however still having issues with IE9-10, which supports mp4. It doesn't play at all. Any other ideas as to what could be causing this? *Edit:* Got it working in IE9 by changing `type="video/m4v"` to `mp4` instead of `m4v`, but IE10 is still not moving!

Comment: I've opened your site in IE10 just now and it's working. I see bear that bubbles, when I save it it's in MPEG-4 video format. Console says that you have HTML1508: Unmatched end tag. on line 209. Try to correct that.

Comment: Well that's strange, browserstack gives me a still image in IE10. How are you testing? I'll take a look at the unmatched tag.

Comment: Fixed IE 11 issues for me by using the AddType in the .htaccess file, cheers Freshbm, you the man!

Comment: it's if using apache, how about nginx ?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is server-side. The server is actually returning `text/plain` as MIME type for the videos (at least the .ogg one). You will need to adjust your server's configuration to return the correct MIME type so that Firefox can correctly recognize the file. It is the same issue described here: [no video with supported format and MIME type found. What does this mean and how can I change this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424729/no-video-with-supported-format-and-mime-type-found-what-does-this-mean-and-how) (you just don't see the message because you don't have the `controls` option in your `<video>` tag).

Answer (score 1):

Your server delivers the resource http://dev.fristil.se/hbh/wp-content/themes/skal/images/video/bubblybeer.webm with the HTTP header `Content-Type: text/plain` – and therefore Firefox refuses to treat it as anything else.

“Teach” your server to deliver such content as `video/webm`.

(Same goes for your ogv – your server also says that resource would be text, should be `video/ogg` instead.)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem w/ webm using the Flowplayer HTML5 player. Firefox said "HTML5 Video Not Found". At first I thought it was Miro having an encode problem and I tried several different programs, all with the same result. So I narrowed it down to either an improper MIME type on my server, transmitting the webm as text/plain (you can use web inspector to see this) or Firefox just sucking. I had the hosting provider AddType video/webm .webm a while ago, so I can't be positive. What I did was just remove the webm reference directly from my HTML after realizing that I had used Flowplayer in the past and only needing a single mp4 file. Firefox can use mp4. Remove this:

```
 <source type="video/webm" src="URL_to_webm.webm" />
```

That made it work on everything (IE, Chrome, Firefox, iPad, iPhone). Chrome 29 on Mac uses the mp4.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem in my windows hosting. To solve this i included the mime setting in web.config inside

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
</staticContent>
```