# HTML5 video tag. Some .MP4 videos don't work in Chrome

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, html, http, blob

We're making our webapp with ASP.NET MVC 5, and we're facing to an strange behaviour while playing our mp4 videos (codec h264 all of them) between web browsers.

These videos are not stored in filesystem, they're stored like BLOBs inside a table of our SQL Server.

The way we link our BLOBs with the HTML5 video tag is with a source that points to an Action that returns a FileStreamResult with ContentType header set properly.

Firefox and IE can play them, but Chrome can't with all. When I click on the 'Play' button, the videoplayer stills showing a black screen. When this happens and play button is clicked, network tab of the browser shows up two 200 HTTP responses: one with the video full size in bytes and the other one showing 0 bytes. No errors on console.

What's wrong with Chrome? What's wrong with us?

Thank you for your time guys, I'm so thankful to this site :)

Comment: What is the content type of HTTP response? Check this answer, maybe can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15656782/1081079

Comment: Hi freshbm, server returns video/mp4. So It doesn't help, thank you anyways.

Comment: Try this then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937480/mp4-not-playing-on-chrome-version-27-0

Comment: @freshbm Then there's no hope at all to expect a good support from Chrome to h264 encoded mp4 videos? I don't like the idea of reencoding every mp4 that we've stored :/

Answer (score 1):

After some time of researching, we found that MP4 videos with h264 codec that exceed 5MB/s bitrate are not played by Chrome HTML5 video player.

Until now our solution is reencoding MP4 videos that exceed that bitrate to solve this.

If anyone has a better answer, it obviously will be appreciated ;). We hope it could work for anyone that has the same problem.