# HTML5 Video Not Working in Firefox - Editing .htaccess Didn't Work?

Tags: html, .htaccess, firefox, video

I'm trying to get an HTML5 video header background working and I've almost got it, but it's not working in Firefox. I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656465/html5-video-not-playing-in-firefox) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139969/video-file-ogv-plays-locally-in-firefox-but-not-from-server), and tried to edit my .htaccess file but it didn't work. I just pasted this at the end of the file:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm

AddType audio/mpeg .mp3
AddType audio/ogg .ogg
AddType audio/mp4 .m4a
AddType audio/wav /wav
```

Was that right?

After trying that, I looked at [Video for Everybody](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody) and the [VFE generator](http://v4e.thewikies.com/). I took the code the generator gave me and pasted it into my site. The video works in Safari and Chrome, but Firefox displays the poster and tells me "No video with supported format and MIME type found." But shouldn't my edit to the .htaccess file have fixed that? What do I need to do to get the video working in Firefox?

Comment: what order do you have the video files in your <video> tag, and do you have a sample we can check?

Comment: The order is mp4 then ogg. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/regularmegs/L2z3e0hy/).

Comment: looking at the fiddle the ogv file is a 404. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14822493/firefox-wont-play-webm-and-ogv-videos-with-html5 for other Firefox ogv hints

Comment: Gah, I can't believe after all that frustration, it was the link that was wrong. The video is now playing in Firefox. It isn't aligning to the top of the page the way it is in the other browsers, but that's a different question, I think.

Comment: :) sometimes it just takes an extra set of eyes (and the browser developer console!)